# PHP how to execute a command

Tags: php, apache, execution

I'm trying to use LibreOffice for converting a spreadsheet to another format, when I execute the command from the console it works fine but when I do it from PHP using exec() or system() it doesn't work.
It doesn't show any error or anything, it simply silently fails, if I try executing some simple command like "ls" it works just fine.

This is the command I'm using:

```
<?php
system("libreoffice --headless -convert-to ooxml '/home/www/path_to_app/file.xlsx' -outdir /home/www/path_to_app/");
```

I already tried changing the apache User and Group on /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf to the same logged in user I am.

I'm wondering if the problem is that the www folder is /home instead of inside my user and that causes permissions problems, but so far couldn't make it work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try specifying the full path to `libreoffice` in your command, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/libreoffice` or wherever it is installed and see if that gets you a little further.

Comment: at risk of being stupid - exec() will not return an error message, are you sure it fails silently? have you tryed passthru()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notwithstanding your $PATH, which drew010 alluded to, I wouldn't do it this way.

LibreOffice is a pretty big program, has lots of code you don't know about, it generates and updates files in a directory in your $HOME, and is certainly not something you're going to be able to run more than one copy of at a time.

So instead of having LibreOffice launched by your web server, and subverting Apache's security by running it as a more privileged user than "www-data" or "nobody", you should make a handler.

First off, verify that you can run your `libreoffice ...` command line from a terminal.  To be extra sure that you don't have any X11 dependencies, run `unset DISPLAY` (for bash) or `unsetenv DISPLAY` (for tcsh) in your xterm before you test your command line.  Does it break?  Fix that problem first.  Does it work?  Great, then proceed with a handler.

Your handler, in its simplest form, can be a script that loops forever, checking for "files to handle" in a spool directory, and if it finds them, converts them using libreoffice and puts the resultant file where it can be found by your web app.

```
#!/bin/sh

while sleep 10; do
  if [ `ls /var/tmp/myspool/ | grep -c '\.xlsx$'` -gt 0 ]; then
    ls /var/tmp/myspool/*.xlsx | while read file; do
      /usr/local/bin/libreoffice --headless -convert-to ooxml "$file" yadda yadda
      if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        mv "$file" "/var/tmp/myspool/done/
      fi
    done
  fi
done
```

If you don't want the overhead of something "polling" (checking the spool directory every 10 seconds), then you could have your PHP script add a line to a log that gets watched by your handler.  For example:

```
<?php

// process form, save file to spool dir
syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Saved: " . $filename);

?>
```

Make sure you've configured syslog to store these messages in, say, `/var/log/filelog`, then your handler can just tail the log.

```
#!/bin/sh

tail -F /var/log/filelog | while read line; do
  filename="`echo \"$line\" | sed 's/.*Saved: //'`"
  /usr/local/bin/libreoffice --headless -convert-to ooxml "$file" yadda yadda
  # etc ... error handling and mv as in the other script
done
```

Get the idea?

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a good approach. It's been long since I moved from this problem but next time I'll try this.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem with the command below :

```
system('
  export HOME=/tmp 
  libreoffice --headless --invisible --norestore --convert-to pdf --outdir /my/folder /my/file/calc.xls');
```

Comment: Similar idea here (http://superuser.com/questions/627266/convert-file-to-pdf-using-libreoffice-under-user-apache-i-e-when-using-php).

Comment: You save my day!, the magic was -> HOME=/tmp , i think it was because apache user dont have any $HOME folder.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem with the command below :

```
exec('libreoffice --headless --invisible --norestore --convert-to pdf --outdir /my/folder /my/file/calc.xls');
```

Just check rights, libreoffice uses user home folder, If you use default settings for Ubuntu then PHP runs oenter code heren www-data rights and it's home is /var/www/, but default this directory is owned by root.enter code here

In PHP - you can see rigths:

```
exec('whoami', $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

In console - You can see your HOME and give correct rights:

```
su wwww-data
echo $HOME
exit;
chown www-data:www-data /var/www -R
```

Comment: This worked for me on Nginx under CentOS: *chown apache:apache /var/www -R*. You saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: work for me too on `CentOS 6.3 x86_64` `libreoffice4.2` ... and most important thank you very much sir..

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem before.....

This solution seems worked for me...

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
} 

$mainFile = "YOUR FILE";     
$cmd2 = "export HOME=/tmp
             libreoffice --headless --invisible --norestore --convert-to pdf " .
                    "'$mainFile'";



        $saved = getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");        // save old value 
        $newld = "/usr/lib";  // extra paths to add 
        if ($saved) {

            putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" . $newld);
        }           
                // set new value 
        //


        // command is loaded using 
        // libs in the new path list 
        execInBackground($cmd2);
        putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$saved");        // restore old value
```