# Unable to execute DOC to PDF conversion command via PHP exec

Tags: php, pdf, centos, libreoffice

I am unable to execute the following command under user apache using php exec function.

```
exec('/usr/bin/libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/coverpage.doc');
```

OS  : CentOS 6.4 Final

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciable. Thanks

Comment: use a php pdf class? dompdf, tcpdf, phpexcel, phpword etcetc

Comment: What happens if you use the command by itself? What user is your PHP running as? Does that user have access to the executeable?

Comment: @h2ooooooo : via direct ssh, command works good. but via php its not working. PHP is running under user apache.

Comment: @LX7 Then I'll ask again - [switch user to the "apache" user](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/how-to-switch-between-users-on-one-terminal) and then run the command. Does it **then** work good?

Comment: @h2ooooooo: No its not working for user apache, Can you please tell me how can i set executable permission for user apache..???

Comment: @LX7 [Perhaps you can try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593724/php-how-to-execute-a-command) or [this](http://superuser.com/questions/627266/convert-file-to-pdf-using-libreoffice-under-user-apache-i-e-when-using-php)

Comment: @LX7 If you figured out how to fix it then make sure to add it as an answer so whoever else has this problem can figure it out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check for the permission given for /var/www folder. Give `apache:apache` as owner for `/var/www/`.

Use the below command to install libreoffice headless package if it is not installed.

```
sudo yum install openoffice.org-headless
```

This has worked for me in centOS.

Comment: Issue was with headless package and I already fixed it. :) . Any way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There may be numerous reasons start by redirecting command error output to a file and then continue troubleshooting from there :

exec('/usr/bin/libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/coverpage.doc 2> /tmp/error.txt');

After running the script check /tmp/error.txt.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would first of all try it with giving absolute paths to the command.
2. I suspect that the libreoffice binary does not work -- you have to locate the soffice binary and see if that works.
3. Then, your --convert-to pdf is not sufficient. It needs to be:

   --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export
4. Next, the command will not work if there is already a LibreOffice GUI instance up and running on your system. Add this additional parameter to your command:

   "-env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/LibreOffice_Conversion_${USER}"
5. Also, make sure that the --outdir /pdf you specify does exist, and that you have write permission to it. Or, rather use a different output dir. Even if it is just for the first testing and this debugging round:

   $ mkdir ${HOME}/lo_pdfs
6. This works for me on Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.5 with LibreOffice v4.4.3.2 (using my specific path for the binary soffice which will be different for you anyway...).

   ```
   /path/to/soffice
   ```

   `--headless`

   `"-env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/LibreOffice_Conversion_${USER}"`

   `--convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export`

   `--outdir ${HOME}/lo_pdfs  path/to/test.docx`

If this will not work try this answer
[Command `libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf test.docx --outdir /pdf` is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349542/command-libreoffice-headless-convert-to-pdf-test-docx-outdir-pdf-is-not)