# How can I convert an .xlsx file to html with bash script?

Tags: html, bash, shell, xlsx

i like to convert .xlsx-files to .html-files with a bash script. Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: It is not possible using vanilla bash. You could use external tools such as python, perl, [libroffice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362464/libreoffice-converting-html-to-xls-or-xlsx) or [gnumeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557360/convert-xlsx-to-csv-in-linux-command-line).

Answer (score 6):

It is possible, with the help of other external programs. For example, if you have LibreOffice installed on your computer, the following Bash code would achieve what you want:

```
libreoffice --invisible --convert-to html /folder/spreadsheet.xlsx --outdir /destination/folder
```

The code above worked fine for LibreOffice version 4.3.3.2.