# Change "LiberationSerif" font when I convert XLSX to PDF via Libreoffice in CLI (soffice)

Tags: excel, pdf, command-line, fonts, libreoffice

**Problem**: When I try to convert xlsx document to PDF, LibreOffice ignores my fonts. It sets "LiberationSerif" for all text. I tried to use "Arial", "Times New Roman" and it did not work.

**Evironment**: Debian 7x64, LibreOffice 5.2.3.3 installed manually from LibreOffice site. The version availeble in aptitude is outdated.

**This is how I try to launch it**:
    sh /opt/libreoffice5.2/program/soffice --headless --infilter="Microsoft Excel 2007/2010 XML" --convert-to pdf:calc_pdf_Export --outdir /path-to-export-pdf /path-to-input-file/file.xlsx

**Additional information**: LibreOffice didn't work for me until I created empty ".openoffice.org" folder in my users' home dir. I did research before I post a question here. There are no similar settings in LibreOffice API.
This answer was really close, but I'm not too good in C to learn source code of LibreOffice
http://nabble.documentfoundation.org/Command-line-PDF-export-options-quot-soffice-convert-to-pdf-quot-td4158804.html

I've found @KurtPfeifle answers exreemly helpful, but I cannot thank him as long as I'm newbie here.
[Command `libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf test.docx --outdir /pdf` is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349542/command-libreoffice-headless-convert-to-pdf-test-docx-outdir-pdf-is-not/30465397#30465397?newreg=7eb36e9c24c44823a30057e4fd15c2cb)

I hope Kurt Pfeifle will read this question, because I'm sure he knows the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. For some reason I expected Arai and Times New Roman to be presented on our server. To get them we had to install ttf-mscorefonts-installer from contrib source of debian.