# Replacement of Google document viewer in china

Tags: documentviewer

I am using the Google document viewer to view the uploaded documents via a browser. It works fine, but the real problem comes from China. Since google services are banned in China, my end users from China cannot able to access the documents via browser.

Could you please recommend a solution for this? Is there any replacement for Google document viewer in China, so that I can view my documents over browser?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.I googled a lot but not find any public viewer like google. However I installed libreoffice on that specific server and converted every docs to pdf (Temporary for just previewing) through libreoffice to show on browser or preview. For conversion to pdf can follow this link  https://stackoverflow.com/q/30349542/5686382