# Apache POI - DOCX To PDF Conversion

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi, docx

I am trying to convert a docx file into pdf file using POI. Getting following error.
Using poi-3.17 ,

```
  import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
    
    public class WordToPDF {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            WordToPDF cwoWord = new WordToPDF();
            System.out.println("Start");
            cwoWord.ConvertToPDF("D:\\2067536.docx", "D:\\2067536.pdf");
        }
    
        public void ConvertToPDF(String docPath, String pdfPath) {
            try {
                InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File(docPath));
                XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);
                document.createStyles();
                PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfPath));
                PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
                System.out.println("Done");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
    
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Here is the Error happening

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:70)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:38)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:45)
        at WordToPDF.ConvertToPDF(WordToPDF.java:27)
        at WordToPDF.main(WordToPDF.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.visitHeader(PdfMapper.java:178)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.internal.PdfMapper.visitHeader(PdfMapper.java:111)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitHeaderRef(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:1142)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.MasterPageManager.visitHeadersFooters(MasterPageManager.java:213)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.MasterPageManager.addSection(MasterPageManager.java:180)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.MasterPageManager.compute(MasterPageManager.java:127)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.MasterPageManager.initialize(MasterPageManager.java:90)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitBodyElements(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:232)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.start(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:199)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:56)
        ... 4 more
```

As this is a null pointer error I am unable to understand what exactly the issue might be, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant part of your code? (Having said that, at a guess, it looks like you are using a 3rd party [converter which is no longer being maintained](https://github.com/yeokm1/docs-to-pdf-converter) - which, in turn, uses Apache POI and other libraries.)

Comment: Looks from the package name like you're on an old version of the converter, what happens when you upgrade to the latest `fr.opensagres` version?

Comment: added the code as well

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440312/docx-to-pdf-converter-in-java) may provide some help, also - along the same lines as Gagravarr's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libre Office Saved my life, Simple one liner command for docx to pdf conversion works like a charm.

Detailed answer here

[Command `libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf test.docx --outdir /pdf` is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349542/command-libreoffice-headless-convert-to-pdf-test-docx-outdir-pdf-is-not)

Comment: This solution suddenly stop working