# Failed to convert doc to pdf using libreoffice5 in php

Tags: php, mysql, libreoffice, unoconv

I got a problem when converting doc to pdf using libreoffice5 in php.

I wrote a Linux shell to convert a office doc document to pdf (t.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
libreoffice5.0 --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf --outdir $1 $2
```

Then I created a php file in apache htdocs dir as follows (mytest.php):

```
<?php 
$cmd = './t.sh ./ ./55ffbc34c3808.docx';
var_dump($cmd);

$rtn = exec($cmd, $rtnResult, $rtnVal);
var_dump($rtnResult);
```

But when I run http://localhost/mytest.php, the page never stop and no result was printed (no pdf was generated).
When I run ps -ef|grep libre, I saw the following:

```
maijin   10403 10402  0 03:11 ?        00:00:00 /opt/libreoffice5.0/program/oosplash --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf --outdir ./ ./55ffbc34c3808.docx
maijin   10420 10403  1 03:11 ?        00:00:00 /opt/libreoffice5.0/program/soffice.bin --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf --outdir ./ ./55ffbc34c3808.docx
maijin   10427  8755  0 03:11 pts/1    00:00:00 grep libre
```

These processes never stop.
I check the libreoffice and it is correct:

```
>ls -l  /usr/local/bin/libreoffice5.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Aug 22 02:54 /usr/local/bin/libreoffice5.0 -> /opt/libreoffice5.0/program/soffice
```

If I run the t.sh shell in linux console, the pdf file can be generated.
Why can't I convert the doc to pdf in php?

Comment: Kill all previous "zombie" soffice process. Get sure apache user has the privileges of creating new files in the directory you want them to be created.

Comment: I killed all zombie but it didn't work. I already did: chmod -R a+rw ./

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593724/php-how-to-execute-a-command . Start with the second answer (the one given by @user1662766). Basically you need to tell libreoffice where is the HOME of the user running it. Which is apache. Which happen to have no HOME. Just check it.